# Filename with percent in URL

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a directory that contains several pdfs, I have a script that sets the path for access and everything else,

```
<a href="<?= get_home_url().'/'.$certificate->file_path.'/'.$certificate->file_name ?>" target="_blank">Baixar</a>
```

however I am having a 404 error in files that contain accents of type (comma and percent),

File with accent:

**http://exodocientifica.com.br//_fispq/ALARANJADO%20DE%20METILA%200,2%.pdf**

other files without accent are normally accessed,

File without accent:
**http://exodocientifica.com.br//_fispq/ALARANJADO%20DE%20METILA.pdf**

already I tried using functions like urlencode, htmlentities, hand did not get results

Answer (score 1):

You should encode `%` with `%25` since it is a special character in URL. Try using this URL instead:

```
http://exodocientifica.com.br//_fispq/ALARANJADO%20DE%20METILA%200,2%25.pdf
```